# Execute crontab as root not working

Tags: linux, bash, backup, crontab

I need to execute a backup script each night. When I execute manually, backup is done without problems, but I use `sudo crontab -e` and add the script there:

```
root@SF-DES-SVN:/home/svn# crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@daily /home/xxx/do_backup.sh &> /tmp/do_backup.log
@daily /home/xxx/do_rm_old.sh &> /tmp/do_rm_old.log
```

But the scripts are not being executed, in the log I have msg:

```
/etc/cron.daily/xxx_backups: line 3: /home/xxx/do_backup.sh: No such file or directory
```

In line 3 of the script

```
SVN_ROOT=/home/svn/
```

Which, of course, exists and keeps all my repositories. But makes me think is a permission problem…

- I tried with patterns instead of annotations, same behaviour.
- I tried with `@hourly` annotation and works, but I think is because root session is open.

Any idea of what's going on?

**UPDATE:**

```
root@SF-DES-SVN:/# cat /etc/fstab
```

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/SF--DES--SERVER-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=fe2e0df4-cd99-4189-8eed-9d7519e2aba8 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
#/dev/mapper/SF--DES--SERVER-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sda3  /home/back_svn ext3 defaults,auto 0 2
```

**UPDATE2:**
 Output for `ls -la /home/siconet/do_backup.sh`

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 siconet siconet 1055 2014-06-05 17:57 /home/siconet/do_backup.sh
```

**UPDATE3:**
 I execute each order after entering as root user with **`sudo su -`**. Am I right when I supose `root@SF-DES-SVN:/home/svn# crontab -l` lists the **root user** crontabs?

Comment: Is `/home/svn/` on the same filesystem as `/`, or is it something you have to mount? It seems strange that file permssions are involved, `crontab` is executed as root. It sounds more like there is a difference in two environments. You could try preceding the line `SVN_ROOT=/home/svn` with `df -h; ls /; ls /home` just to see what the script sees.

Comment: Changes done, will see tomorrow what log has. About location: all folders and scripts are at same machine. The only remote action is performed when programming the crontab, I connect remotely by SSH with putty and configure crontab as root... but the crontab is done in repository server, no  mounted unit.

Comment: You say "In line 3 of the bash".  This phrase does not make any sense.  I guess you mean line 3 of the shell ***script*** `do_backup.sh`.  But that isn't what the error message is talking about, it's saying that it has a problem *on line 3 **of the crontab file*** — i.e., the `@daily /home/xxx/do_backup.sh …` line.  So, the question is: if you type `sudo -i`, then `cd /root` (or `cd /`) and `/home/xxx/do_backup.sh`, does that work?  Are you 100% sure that you have it spelled correctly, and that you have the directory right?  Are you sure it isn't `/home/xxx/bin/do_backup.sh`?

Comment: Wait — are you saying that you have the scripts on one machine, and that you ssh to a different machine  to configure the crontab?  So, the question is: are the scripts accessible from the place where you run `crontab -e`?

Comment: @Scott *About location: all folders and scripts are at same machine.*

Comment: after `sudo -i` and `cd /` result of `/home/xxx/do_backup.sh` is script executed ok with screen verbose instead of sending to log file as explained in the question

Comment: Is your home directory auto-mounted?  If you do `@daily (ls -la /home; ls -la /home/xxx) > /tmp/ls.log 2>&1`, what does it show?

Comment: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'ls'`

Comment: about home directory I thik is not mounted, is a local folder... how can I check it?

Comment: Pls add the content of the file /etc/fstab to the original post

Comment: @MariusMatutiae done.